# LASSO: All KKT-Conditions

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, derivative

I'm trying to code the lasso algorithm via coordinate descent by myself. However, I want to implement a check for the KKT-conditions as in [this blog](http://jocelynchi.com/a-coordinate-descent-algorithm-for-the-lasso-problem). But what are all KKT conditions for the LASSO ?

$Lagr(\beta, \lambda) =\min\limits_{\beta} \left\{ \frac{1}{2N} \sum_{i=1}^N\left(y_{i}- \sum_{j=1}^p\beta_{j}\tilde{x}_{ij}\right)^2  +\lambda\sum_{j=1}^p\left|\beta_{j}\right| \right\}$

I often only the the stationary condition. 
In the reffered block, they derived at one way the KKT-conditions by spliting up the $\beta$ into $\beta^+$ and $\beta^-$ (have a closer look to the page). I'm not sure if this is the right or only way to derive all KKT-conditions.
Is there a way to do it more general instead of Splitting the $\beta$'s ?